# How can delete added UiElement

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I added uielement textbox to ligtningchartjs. I want to delete uielement ligtningchartjs on scale.

```
this.chart .addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox) .setDraggingMode(UIDraggingModes.notDraggable) .setText('ID: ' + label) .setPosition({ x: xPosition + 1.6, y: 88 })
```